# How to delete row with locked cells using EPPLUS

Tags: c#, epplus

I have created an import/export Excel in ASP Core 1.0 with epplus core and I handled insert/update/delete.

So for each object in my excel, if it has an id, then it will be updated, if it doesn't then it will be inserted and if an id in the excel is in the database and not in the excel, I delete the row in database.

But, I used a protection on my sheet, because I hid some columns and I don't want user to see them(like the id column for example). So the user can't resize the hidden columns.

So the user have to right-click on a row an select "delete row" to delete a row. But I have an error because Excel don't want to delete a row with "locked" cells.

how could I handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by inserting macro in your sheet:

as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982783/excel-allow-user-to-delete-a-row-containing-protected-cells)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address Like "$" & Target.Row & ":$" & Target.Row Then
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Else
ActiveSheet.Protect
End If
End Sub
```

Using Epplus after you do whatever operations on your file just add the following:

```
string code = "Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal 

Target As Range)\n" +
"If Target.Address Like \"$\" & Target.Row & \":$\" & Target.Row Then\n" +
"ActiveSheet.Unprotect\n" +
"Else\n" +
"ActiveSheet.Protect\n" +
"End If\n" +
"End Sub\n" ;
package.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();
worksheet.CodeModule.Code = code;
```

The above code will protect your sheet and still allow user to delete rows.