# Excel: Allow user to delete a row containing protected cells – crashes

Tags: vba, excel

I ve added this VBA do my document. But the code keeps crashing at this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect
```

I have no idea where to start?1

[Excel: allow user to delete a row containing protected cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982783/excel-allow-user-to-delete-a-row-containing-protected-cells)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address Like "$" & Target.Row & ":$" & Target.Row Then
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Else
ActiveSheet.Protect
End If
End Sub
```

**Update:** 
The error occurs whenever I select a protected cell twice in a row.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: It says Error 1004

Comment: try this ActiveSheet.Protect contents:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True

Comment: You can't protect an already protected sheet. You could try adding `ActiveSheet.Unprotect` before `ActiveSheet.Protect`.

Comment: @Lisa11: Good idea. But it does not help. I now got an error on the new Line 'ActiveSheet.Unprotect'

Comment: @pokemon_Man Does not help as well :-(

Comment: The error occurs whenever I select a protected cell twice in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have any issues with your code snippet, but you could only protect the sheet when it is not protected like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address Like "$" & Target.Row & ":$" & Target.Row Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Else
        If Not ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
            ActiveSheet.Protect
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This just wraps the protect statement in an if statement that checks to see if the sheet is not protected before it tries to protect the sheet.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be much more stable. I'll monitor the performance over the next days.